# How to make a folder static in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get a picture from my folder with a path refer from my `json` and display it in `FeaturedRooms.jsx`.

```
...
src
  components
    FeaturedRooms.jsx
  images
  pages
    Home.jsx
context.jsx
...
```

```
...
"images":[
{
"url":"../images/room-1.jpeg"
},
...
```

I'm using the `context.jsx` to handle and store the data.

```
const fetchUrl = async () => {
    const resp = await fetch(url);
    const respData = await resp.json();
    const rooms = respData.rooms;
    featured(rooms);
    dispatch({ type: "ROOMS", payload: rooms });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUrl();
  }, []);

  const featured = (rooms) => {
    let featuredRooms = rooms.filter((room) => room.room.featured === true);
    dispatch({ type: "FEATURED_ROOMS", payload: featuredRooms });
  };
```

And I'm trying to display it on the `FeaturedRooms.jsx`.

```
<div className="featured-wrapper">
        {featuredRooms.map((rooms) => {
          const { system, room } = rooms;
          let images = room.images.map((image) => {
            return image.url;
          });
          return (
            <div className="room" key={system.id}>
              <h2>{room.name}</h2>
              <img src={images[0]} alt="featured-rooms" />
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
```

But it's not working at all, is there a way for me to access it? And also, is there a way for me to make the `images` folder a static folder? Perhaps I will be accessing the `images` folder from a different folder.

edit: some more details.

Comment: Static content should be in the public directory. Assets in the `src` directory should be imported. Can you show us how you are trying to access/render these images?

Comment: I edited my post, please look at it, it should be there.

Answer (score 0):

Your folder structure is correct. What you need to do in your array is

```
...
"images":[
{
"url":require("../images/room-1.jpeg")
},
...
```

Then whenever you want to use this images array

```
images.map((item) =>(
   <img src={item.url} />

))
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It didn't recognize the ```require```.

Comment: @BaBi `require` doesn't work in JSON files, but you can process the JSON file in to Javascript object and require the images then. `<img src={require(images[0])} alt="featured-rooms" />`.

Comment: You need to change the file to js. The only difference would allocating the object to a variable. Something like ```const data = ...your json file```